# WPF project within another WPF project. Commands not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a project solution that contains 2 WPF projects. Project B is contained, and called, from within project A.

The issue I'm having, is that the button commands on project B MainWindow are not hitting it's corresponding ViewModel. This doesn't happen when I run Project B as a standalone application (everything's fine).

In both Projects A and B, I'm using Galasofts MVVM light framework, housing my view models in the static ViewModelLocator class.

Any idea's would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Edit: For simplicity, I've just included 1 button.

```
ribbon:RibbonControl xmlns:Designer="clr-namespace:Nouvem.LabelDesigner.View.Designer"  x:Class="Nouvem.LabelDesigner.View.Designer.DesignerView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"           
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:systemMessage="clr-namespace:Nouvem.LabelDesigner.View.SystemMessage"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:Nouvem.Shared.Localisation;assembly=Nouvem.Shared"
        UseLayoutRounding="True"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1200"
        Background="White"
        DataContext="{Binding LabelDesigner, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    </Grid>

</ribbon:RibbonControl>
```

ViewModel

```
 public RelayCommand TestCommand { get; set; }

 public LabelDesignerViewModel()
        {
            if (this.IsInDesignMode)
            {
                return;
            }    

            this.TestCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                // test - not hitting when called from another project
            });
}
`
```

Comment: Can you provide simple examples of the code you have which handles these commands? Please include both the XAML, and the C#.

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like `new ProjectB.MainWindow.Show()` in Project A, then all logic in `Project B/App.xaml.cs` and resources in `Project B/App.xaml` are ignored.
if you run Project A, then `Application.Current` is `ProjectA.App` and ProjectB.App is not instantiated.

there are two solutions:

**1. Create Project B as library:**

create new shared library called `Project B Library`, which you will reference from Project A as well as from Project B. Project B will be just an exe container.

**2. Start Project B as new Process**

use `Process.Start()` method to start Project B. You can interact with Project B trought WCF using netNamedPipeBinding